# pros and cons of Avro - JSON / binary serialization

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, avro

I've recently started working with Apache-Avro and would like to serialize my Kafka Topics. Now I've read that Avro offers both Json and binary serialization. Are there any pros and cons? Is not the binary solution better?

Kind regards,
nika

Comment: The existing Avro serializer provided by Confluent doesn't offer JSON avro encoding

Comment: Possible considerations are that Avro comes with libraries for C/C++/C# (amongst others). That makes it more readily interoperable than just plain old JSON. Arguments in favour of JSON is that a JSON schema can express size and value constraints, which a decent JSON validator will honour. This makes it a more complete serialisation, as you can set limits on the sizes of arrays and the values of numbers, and checking is automatic and error free. I don't think Avro's IDL supports constraints, so such limits have to be communicated from dev to dev by some other error prone means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are looking for:

- Binary - smaller data and faster serialization.
- JSON - good for debugging and web-based applications.

Pay attention that a JSON schema is transferred in any case.

Comment: JSON schema isn't transferred in all binary formats. Not even in Avro if using schema registry

Comment: What about JSON + gzip/snappy?